# Set the mouse cursor position in a "Metro" windows 8 program

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, mouse

I am trying to set the position of the mouse cursor (so I can lock it in the center of the screen for the fps I am making) and can not figure out a way to do this.

I need to set the cursor in the middle of the screen each frame so I can make the games camera handle correctly (typical FPS camera) and without a mouse.setposition equivalent this cannot be done to my knowledge.

I am writing my program in c#, for the windows 8 store.

I have already tried:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
```

Comment: Need I ask what the result of that attempt was?

Comment: It was a failure sadly, I may have done it wrong however. Any tips?

Comment: What kind of failure? A failure of calling the function resulting in exception, or a silent failure where the position just stay as it were, or it jumped randomly?

Comment: It fails silently where the cursor just stays as it were.

I am also unsure of if this call would work in windows rt on arm too.

Comment: @DanielArmstrong Not really sure if this would work on Windows RT but can't you just do `Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);`? Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Martheen I also have tried using "Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = null;" now too and this seems to stop the cursor from rendering but does not lock it in the screen like it does in the c++ version.

Comment: @PicrofoEGY Sadly the Cursor class is not supported in windows 8.

Comment: @GolezTrol It failed silently with no crash, i did manage to use getPosition from c# to c++ with no issue, so it is just setPosition that is not working.

Comment: I just spoke to some Microsoft people, it isn't doable at the moment and they hope to add in the next api release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just spoke to some Microsoft people, it isn't doable at the moment and they hope to add in the next api release.